# xmlrpc over nginx w/ scgi

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm trying to configure rtorrent with xmlrpc using nginx as the web server. I'm running into an issue right now where, when I run this command:
`xmlrpc localhost/rpc system.listMethods`
I get a 502. nginx logs this error:
`connect() to unix:/tmp/scgi.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /rpc/RPC2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "scgi://unix:/tmp/scgi.socket:", host: "localhost"`

I'm setting the permissions for the socket properly (I think). I've been working on this for a bit, and would appreciate another set of eyes. You can find all the conf files and code here: https://github.com/nVitius/rtorrent-docker
Also, dockerhub link:
https://hub.docker.com/r/nvitius/rtorrent-docker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at it again this morning, I found that the issue was that rtorrent wasn't picking up the configuration file. I specified the path to it manually, and it works now.